# How to convert PPT presentation slides into images using laravel | angular

Tags: php, angular, laravel, office365, powerpoint

I wanted to make a slider screen using angular like image slider. For example i have did with images uploaded images using laravel and saved them in s3 bucket and made them slide in angular using api call we can get data. Likewise i want to use PPT want to upload ppt file that should slide in my screen and all the slides of ppt should slide like images this is the flow. i have seen many things like showing the ppt with slide controls same like ms ppt but i want to make all automatic slider using ppt slides. Is there any ways in laravel or angular for splitting each slide as images or something else.

I have tried like this.

This is my component.html file

```
<div class="office-viewer">
    <iframe [src]='urlSafe' width='100%' height='100%' frameborder='0'></iframe>
</div>
```

This is my component.ts file

```
urlppt: string =
    'https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=https://hep-dev.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/tv-slider-app/samplepptx_a41ed05d0eeb8aac10946c61f4afba17.pptx';

 this.urlSafe = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
       this.urlppt
 );
```

Here iframe is used for displaying the page and just setting the urlSafe for source. It will shows the whole ppt in web like web view of ms powerpoint because it is using (https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?) viewer. In my case i want all my slides as a separate slides and it should automatically slide like image sliders.

Is there any ways to separate the ppt slides into images using laravel. I have used one method using phpoffice/phppresentation package.

First installed `composer require phpoffice/phppresentation`

```
    use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\IOFactory;
    use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Slide;

    public function convertToImages(Request $request)
    {
    $pptxFile = $request->file('sample.pptx');

    $request->validate([
        'pptxFile' => 'required|mimetypes:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation'
    ]);

    try {
        $presentation = IOFactory::load($pptxFile);
        $slides = $presentation->getAllSlides();
        $imageUrls = [];

        foreach ($slides as $index => $slide) {
            $imagePath = 'images/slide_' . ($index + 1) . '.jpg';
            $this->saveSlideImage($slide, $imagePath);
            $imageUrls[] = asset($imagePath);
        }

        return response()->json(['images' => $imageUrls]);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'An error occurred during conversion'], 500);
    }
}

 private function saveSlideImage(Slide $slide, $imagePath)
 {
     $thumbnail = $slide->createThumbnail();
    
     if ($thumbnail !== null) {
         imagejpeg($thumbnail, public_path($imagePath));
         imagedestroy($thumbnail);
     }
 }
```

In the above the method will convert slides to images and save it to a path. But in my case throwing createThumbnail() method is undefined error. How can i resolve or any other ways.